# Modal Dialog containing a webpart

Tags: 2010, modal-dialog

My ideal situation is to have a "Preview" option available for subsites. I thought perhaps a good way of doing this would be to have a modal dialog pop up containing some of the subsite's information, including a brief description and a couple of recently added items. Is it possible to create this? Maybe if the modal dialog contains a data query webpart or something similar?
Im new to this side of sharepoint so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is simple, You can create custom web part to accomplish your requirement. In your custom web part you can place number of subsites list with description.